# Jquery thumbnail scroller with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a jquery thumbnail scroller with buttons that work on mousedown and mouseup events . I can do the scrolling but when i try to make a function out of it to use it again n again , it dont work . Here is my code for the scroller

```
                var $wrapper = $('.my_ul');
                var $div = $('.my_div');
                var $ul = $('.my_ul');


                    function scrollRight()
                    {


                        var divLeft = $ul.css('marginLeft');
                        divLeft = Math.abs(parseInt(divLeft)) - 60;


                        var width = $div.width();
                        var ulwid = $ul.width();

                        var ulWidth = $ul.width() - width;
                        if(divLeft >= ulWidth){stopScrolling();}
                        else{
                        // contintually increase scroll position*/
                        $wrapper.animate({'margin-left' : '-=10'}, 1, scrollRight);}

                    }

                    function scrollLeft()
                    {   
                        var divLeft = $ul.css('marginLeft');
                        divLeft = parseInt(divLeft);


                        if(divLeft >= 0){stopScrolling();}
                        else{
                        // contintually increase scroll position*/
                        $wrapper.animate({'margin-left' : '+=10'}, 1, scrollLeft);}

                    }

                    function stopScrolling()
                    {
                        // stop increasing scroll position
                        $wrapper.stop();
                    }

                    $('.scroll_right').mousedown(scrollRight).mouseup(stopScrolling);
                    $('.scroll_left').mousedown(scrollLeft).mouseup(stopScrolling);
```

I need to make a function using parameters but when i try that , it dont work . Moreover , The animation gets slow because of the recursive calls . If anyone have any better solutions , please let me know .

Comment: There is no recursion. Each call to scrollRight exits after beginning the animation. After the animation finishes, a timer event (probably) calls scrollRight again. You are moving 10 pixels at a time. Move more pixels at a time and it will scroll faster. Or you can reduce the animation time with the optional parameter.

Comment: What do you want to parameterize?

Comment: You should show a little HTML so we know how the div and the ul relate.

Comment: i wanted to make certain scroll bars but i didn't want to write different codes for different classes . i wanted to make a function so that each time for a scrollbar , i just have to enter the parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
function scrollingStuff($right, $left, $wrapper, $div, $ul) {

    $right.mousedown(scrollRight).mouseup(stopScrolling);
    $left.mousedown(scrollLeft).mouseup(stopScrolling);

    ... put functions here ...

}
```

Call it with the result of a jQuery selector for the elements.

```
scrollingStuff($(".scroll_right"), $(".scroll_left"), ...);
```

Comment: did the trick . thanks . n let me know if there is any better solution to do this scrolling animation

Answer (score 1):

This would move twice as fast:

```
 $wrapper.animate({'margin-left' : '+=20'}, 1, scrollLeft);}
```

I would use a little delay. This is 1/60 sec:

```
$wrapper.animate({'margin-left' : '+=10'}, 16, scrollLeft);}
```

I also think you can move this part out of the function and not call jQuery twice. It doesn't change during the scrolling or even after loading the div and the ul's:

```
var width = $div.width();
var ulwid = $ul.width();
var ulWidth = ulwid - width;
```

Comment: yes i just added them to check somethings . forgot to remove them . But when i try to make function with paramerters so that i can repeat the same code for different container divs and ul elements , it dont work . Please make a jquery function with parameters outta it . thanks